# Calculate histogram graphic columns height

Tags: javascript, graphics, histogram, calculated-columns, histogram2d

I cannot figure out the easiest formula to calculate the height of column in histogram graphic.

For example, I have an array of data

`var data = [82, 61, 88, 245, 201, 619, 735, 1099, 1088, 1477, 1531, 1717, 1263, 1674, 1254, 1134, 718, 887, 748, 569, 485, 565, 286, 266, 298, 203, 171, 235, 128, 127, 109, 128, 76, 73, 73, 85, 44, 33, 47, 29, 38, 47, 35, 31, 16, 17, 11, 20, 20, 276]`

This is the list of numbers (each number in array represents the count of properties closer to edges of the range from 0 to 3000). I need max column height to be 30px. What kind of calculations should I make?

[image: example of result]

I imagine that my pseudocode should look as follows:

```
var maxPropertiesNumber = Math.max.apply(null, data);
var html = list.map(column => {
   var style = {
     width: 10px,
     backgroundColor: 'grey',
     height: ...
   };
   return <div style={style}></div>
})
```

Comment: I don't believe we have enough information to assist you, however from the littler information provided I presume it is price range max / 100?  More importantly in your graph there is data at 3000 but in the array there isn't any 3000...

Comment: @abc123 maybe I didn't describe well, numbers in array are count of properties, e.g. `[82 `- properties that have their price closer to 0 `... 276` - properties that have their price closer to 3000 `]`

Comment: To clarify, do you want your column heights to be calibrated on an absolute scale (to get 30px you must have 3000) or on a relative scale (if your largest value was 1000, that entry would have a height of 30px with everything else scaled accordingly)?

Comment: @Kaitain relatively to the highest number in array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Find the maximum value in the array.
2. Calculate: 30px / (maximum value) = pixels-per-unit
3. Loop through values and perform calculation: round(value *
           pixel-per-unit)